# based on first observable data call other service and wait until service gives result

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I do come across one tricky situation where I do have following scenario.

Based on my first observable result I am planning to call service first service1.

Same time I do need to call service2 and need to wait until service1 and service2 gives data back.

I was thinking to use switchmap to get data from first observable and then use the combineLatest for other 2 services but not getting proper syntax.

I have tried below

```js
getData() {
    //loading start
    this.query.currentData$
        .pipe(
            switchMap((code) => {
                // want to use combine latest
                // need to call 2 services and wait until gets data
                //once both data comes load child components
                //add finalize for services
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                //loading stop
                return throwError(error);
            }),
            finalize(() =>
                //loading stop
            ),
            takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {});

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `forkJoin` to wait for two or more service responses

```
getData() {
    //loading start
    this.query.currentData$
        .pipe(
            switchMap((code) => {
                return forkJoin([this.service1(code), this.service2(code)])
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                //loading stop
                return throwError(error);
            }),
            finalize(() =>
                //loading stop
            ),
            takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {});

}
```